# How to fix crash in PJSIP Android Xamarin.Forms (Endpoint_libCreate)

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.forms, pjsip

I have been trying to integrate PJSIP into my Xamarin.Forms app. I successfully got the iOS version to work, but have been facing a crash on the Android version and have not found a solution for it. I tried all PJSIP versions from 2.8 to 2.10 with the same issue. I also went back to the sample `pjsua2xamarin` application and I got the same crash.

Crash log:

```
[Mono] Found as 'CSharp_pjsua2xamarinfpjsua2_Endpoint_libCreate___'.
[libc] Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1, fault addr 0x0 in tid 30101
```

I did these things:

1. Followed the instructions in ticket 2086 of PJSIP.
2. Followed "[Getting Started: Building for Android](https://trac.pjsip.org/repos/wiki/Getting-Started/Android)".
3. Added the following Android permissions in Manifest just to be comprehensive since Ticket 2086 mentions that a crash in the initialization phase is most probably related to permissions:

   ```
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS" />
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.USE_SIP" />
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
   ```
4. I’m trying to run in an emulator and Android SDK version 22, so I don’t have to worry about requesting permissions.
5. I  also tried different NDK versions from r13b to r20 and tried targeting various Android SDK levels.
6. I used the following configure parameters:

   ```
   APP_PLATFORM=android-18 TARGET_ABI=x86 ./configure-android --use-ndk-cflags --disable-video
   ```

I’m not sure what I can do to debug this issue. Has anybody had this problem? What can I do to debug this when running within Xamarin Visual Studio?

Answer (score 1):

After debugging further, it turns out that the crash is caused due to an underlying issues with pjsip. It is not deigned to work properly with Xamarin. The underlying pjsip code utilizes the JNI_OnLoad function to retrieve the JavaVM pointer. Due to the way libraries are loaded in Xamarin, the JNI_OnLoad is never called. This pointer is used to create GUID. I have modified the underlying code (guid_android.c) to create the guid string similar to the way that is done in (guid_simple.c) without needing the JavaVM pointer. Now the Endpoint.LibCreate does not crash.

However, I suspect that the JavaVM pointer may be used somewhere else.

Answer (score 0):

I have recently updated the instruction in https://github.com/pjsip/pjproject/issues/2086.

Specifically, you need to call `Java.Lang.JavaSystem.LoadLibrary("pjsua2")` in order for `JNI_OnLoad` to be called.